# Skipping the console the first time in Java?

Tags: java, console, skip

Below is a segment of code I'm having problems with in Java; it seems to have traded one problem for another. I was having problems with retrieving user input when it's a sentence due to whitespace errors; I fixed that by adding "nextLine" instead of just "next".

But now, instead of giving the user a chance to answer the first question, it skips the console box and simply outputs "wrong" before going on to question two, where the first console box for the user now shows up.

I double-checked: with "next", the console for question number one shows up, but with "nextLine", it skips that console box (doesn't give the user a chance to type anything), spits out "wrong", and then goes to question two, where the user can finally type something.

Why is it doing this?

```
if(nwb.equalsIgnoreCase("numbers")){
    System.out.println("You must type in the rules verbatim "+
        "(word for word, including punctuation), "+
        "as shown on the Student Hand-Out. "+
        "Capitalization does not matter.");
    int count = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<=(rules.length-1); i++){
        System.out.print("Rule #"+count);
        String response = console.nextLine().replaceAll(" ","");
        if(response.replaceAll(" ", "").equalsIgnoreCase(rules[i].replaceAll(" ", ""))){
            System.out.println("CORRECT");
        }else{
            System.out.println("WRONG\nThe correct wording is: "+rules[i]);
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Highlight the code and press ctrl+k.

Comment: Ah! That's how it's done. Thanks, and sorry about that.

Comment: rules is the name of a String array earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit tedious to read your code, use the { } code block formatter so its easier to read.

try using the `trim()` function for removing blank spaces that come before and after their input.

It might be because you have initialized your response string in the loop, try moving it out and see what that does. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: These suggestions are better suited as comments, not answers. I would recommend deleting your answer as you may get down-votes (not by me though)

Comment: I was adding my answer, my bad, I accidentally submitted it early.

Comment: Is the whitespace the problem? The error only shows up when I replace "next" with "nextLine". I'm not sure how to use trim() (I'm very new to Java), but I can look it up.

Comment: @Ray25Lee No, but that will reduce other possible issues in the future. Try declaring your input and scanner outside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
String response = console.nextLine();
    response = response.trim(); //remove spaces
    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(rules[i].trim())){
        System.out.println("CORRECT");
    }else{
        System.out.println("WRONG\nThe correct wording is: "+rules[i]);
    }
```

there were sevral things to fix . you were replacing the whitespaces. and on your if loop you were removing the whitespaces again. and use trim() function to remove whitespaces.check with this example

Comment: I thought here'd be some repetition with whitespace coding, but the problem isn't the whitespace; I fixed that already. The problem is the code not allowing the user to answer the first question before it goes on to the second question. I fixed it to your example, and it's still doing that.

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern, I did some searching elsewhere, and after a few hours, I came across something that [solved it](https://christprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/java-common-mistakes-1/);

Basically, what I did was this:

```
if(nwb.equalsIgnoreCase("numbers")){
                    System.out.println("You must type in the rules verbatim (word for word, including puncutation), as shown on the Student Hand-Out. Capitalization does not matter.");
                    int count = 1;
                    for(int i = 0; i<=(rules.length-1); i++){
                        System.out.print("Rule #"+count);                            
                        String derpTest = console.nextLine();
                        String response = console.nextLine().replaceAll(" ","");
                        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(rules[i].replaceAll(" ",""))){
                            System.out.println("CORRECT");
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("WRONG\nThe correct wording is: "+rules[i]);
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
}
```

The String derpTest is used up, from what I can tell, and so it all proceeds to String response. I have no vague idea WHY this works; I don't quite understand what the link is saying, so, if someone is up for explaining it, that'd be wicked awesome. Thanks to everyone who tried to figure this out, it's a weird one.

Comment: Correction; you need to put the derpTest String on the OUTSIDE of the loop, or when you move on to questions two, three, etc., it gets weird again. Put it outside the loop, for some reason, it all works fine. Still don't get it, but, ey. Whatever.